# How to truncate text from MySQL database with PHP? (Add '...' after characters limited)

Tags: php, html, text, truncate

I want to show snippets of 2 posts on the homepage. Here is the code I have:

```
    function getPostsHome() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 0,2") or die(mysql_error());
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<h3>" . $post['Title'] . "</h3>";
        echo "<p>" . $post['Content'] . "</p><br /><br />";

    }
}
```

How do I truncate the Title to 25 characters, then '...', and the content to 100 characters, then '...'?

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need php for this, read more on **css**: `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
function getPostsHome() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 0,2") or die(mysql_error());
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      echo "<h3>" . (strlen($post['Title']) > 25 ? substr($post['Title'], 0, 25)."..." : $post['Title']) . "</h3>";
      echo "<p>" . (strlen($post['Content']) > 100 ? substr($post['Content'], 0, 100)."..." : $post['Content']) . "</p><br /><br />";
    }
}
```

sorry, now it's fixed

Comment: Thanks this worked, apart from the second Title not showing at all?

Answer (score 0):

use  `substr()` and `strlen()` functions:

Replace:

```
  echo "<h3>" . $post['Title'] . "</h3>";
```

With:

```
if(strlen($post['Title']) >25)
  echo "<h3>" . substr($post['Title'],0,25)."....</h3>";
else
   echo "<h3>" . $post['Title'] . "</h3>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help :D

```
<?php
    function trunc($str, $len) {
        if (strlen($str) > $len) {
            $str = substr($str, 0, $len) . "...";
        }
        return $str;
    }


    $title = trunc($title, 25);
    $content = trunc($content, 100);

    echo $title;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers can produce strange results. Consider a string of 26 characters. In the other answers, this string is truncated to 25 chars + 3 "...". 28 chars for a string 26. That is not what you want. The good answer therefore is:

```
<?php
    function trunc($str, $len) {
        if (strlen($str) > $len+3) {
            $str = substr($str, 0, $len) . "...";
        }
        return $str;
    }


    $title = trunc($title, 25);
    $content = trunc($content, 100);

    echo $title;

?>
```